# Compute percentile rank relative to a given population

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, rank, percentile

I have "reference population" (say, `v=np.random.rand(100)`) and I want to compute percentile ranks for a given set (say, `np.array([0.3, 0.5, 0.7])`).

It is easy to compute one by one:

```
def percentile_rank(x):
    return (v<x).sum() / len(v)
percentile_rank(0.4)
=> 0.4
```

(actually, there is an ootb [`scipy.stats.percentileofscore`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.10.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html) - but it does *not* work on vectors).

```
np.vectorize(percentile_rank)(np.array([0.3, 0.5, 0.7]))
=> [ 0.33  0.48  0.71]
```

This produces the expected results, but I have a feeling that there should be a built-in for this.

I can also cheat:

```
pd.concat([pd.Series([0.3, 0.5, 0.7]),pd.Series(v)],ignore_index=True).rank(pct=True).loc[0:2]

0    0.330097
1    0.485437
2    0.718447
```

This is bad on two counts:

1. I don't want the test data `[0.3, 0.5, 0.7]` to be a part of the ranking.
2. I don't want to waste time computing ranks for the reference population.

So, what is the *idiomatic* way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setup:

```
In [62]: v=np.random.rand(100)

In [63]: x=np.array([0.3, 0.4, 0.7])
```

Using Numpy broadcasting:

```
In [64]: (v<x[:,None]).mean(axis=1)
Out[64]: array([ 0.18,  0.28,  0.6 ])
```

Check:

```
In [67]: percentile_rank(0.3)
Out[67]: 0.17999999999999999

In [68]: percentile_rank(0.4)
Out[68]: 0.28000000000000003

In [69]: percentile_rank(0.7)
Out[69]: 0.59999999999999998
```

Comment: when both `v` and `x` are `Series` (columns in a `DataFrame`), I get `ValueError: Lengths must match to compare`.

Comment: @sds, in this case you can do it this way: `(v.values<x.values[:,None]).mean(axis=1)`

Answer (score 2):

I think `pd.cut` can do that

```
s=pd.Series([-np.inf,0.3, 0.5, 0.7])
pd.cut(v,s,right=False).value_counts().cumsum()/len(v)
Out[702]: 
[-inf, 0.3)    0.37
[0.3, 0.5)     0.54
[0.5, 0.7)     0.71
dtype: float64
```

Result from your function

```
np.vectorize(percentile_rank)(np.array([0.3, 0.5, 0.7]))
Out[696]: array([0.37, 0.54, 0.71])
```

Comment: this seems to rely on the test scores being sorted. I would rather avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.quantile.html#pandas-series-quantile):

```
np.random.seed(123)
v=np.random.rand(100)

s = pd.Series(v)
arr = np.array([0.3,0.5,0.7])

s.quantile(arr)
```

Output:

```
0.3    0.352177
0.5    0.506130
0.7    0.644875
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I think this is the _inverse_ of the function I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a little late to the party, but wanted to add that pandas has another way to get what you are after with [`Series.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html). Just use the `pct=True` option.